# How can I add a link to DataGridViewLinkColumn

Tags: vb.net

How can I add a link to `DataGridViewLinkColumn`?

Here is my code:

```vb
Dim linkColumn As New DataGridViewLinkColumn
linkColumn.Name = "Links"
dgv.Columns.Add(linkColumn)
dgv.Rows.Add("URL", "TEXT")
```

What is the code for `URL` and `LINKTEXT`?

Answer (score 1):

To display the same link text for every cell, set the UseColumnTextForLinkValue property to true and set the Text property to the desired link text.

Try this.

```
Private Sub AddLinkColumn()

    Dim links As New DataGridViewLinkColumn()
    With links
        .UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True
        .HeaderText = ColumnName.ReportsTo.ToString()
        .DataPropertyName = ColumnName.ReportsTo.ToString()
        .ActiveLinkColor = Color.White
        .LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault
        .LinkColor = Color.Blue
        .TrackVisitedState = True
        .VisitedLinkColor = Color.YellowGreen
    End With
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(links)
End Sub
```